# Ugly border appears at design time, but in runtime its fixed On Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried to add Aero Snap Effect on a border less form.I have successfully done adding Aero Snap Effect but my problem is when I try to rebuild the project it gives me a ugly border on right and bottom side in design time.but when I click start then the ugly border is gone. And it work everything fine...

Problems :
1) for each time when I try to rebuild the project then an ugly border appears on the desinger in design time...but it's gone in runtime and everything fine in runtime

2) for each time when I try to rebuild the project then the forms size is increasing a little bit automatically in designer on design time. But it fixes on runtime

My Code

I used Create Params to remove border and make it Aero Snap

```
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
 {
       get
       {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x40000; //WS_SIZEBOX;
            return cp;
       }                           
 }
```

Comment: The old designer has quite a few limitations, so Microsoft is building a new one, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Updating-the-WinForms-Designer-for-NET-Core-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a design-time problem only, and you don't care not applying that style in design-time, then you can apply it only on run-time.

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                cp.Style |= 0x40000; //WS_SIZEBOX;
            }

            return cp;
        }
    }
```